# How to predefine combobox items for a data binded combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I want to allow user to choose the baud rate of a serial port. 
I created a textbox binded with serial port baud rate as below and it works.

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbbaudRate" Text="{Binding SerialPort.BaudRate}" />
```

My problem is, there is limited sets of valid baud rate. Valid baud rates are { 75, 110, 300, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200 }. I want to change the text box to a combo box listing valid baud rate values.

Heres what i did.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="tbbaudRate" Text="{Binding SerialPort.BaudRate}" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="75"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="110"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="300"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1200"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2400"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="4800"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="9600"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="19200"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="38400"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="57600"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="115200"/>
</ComboBox>
```

While this works, i have few problems.

1. When i first loaded the window, the default values for baudrate is not selected(9600).
2. This doesnt look so elegant. What is the best way to accomplished this?

For reference, here are my serial port class. Also ugly like above code. I use resharper to autogenerate notifypropertychange codes.

```
class SerialComm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int[] ValidBaudRate = new[] { 75, 110, 300, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200 }; //Dont know how to use this
    private int[] ValidDataBits = new[] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; //Dont know how to use this

    private SerialPort _serialPort;

    public SerialComm()
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();
    }

    public SerialPort SerialPort
    {
        get { return _serialPort; }
        set
        {
            _serialPort = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SerialPort");
            SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        }
    }

    #region Autogenerate by resharper
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change you Combobox like this:

```
<ComboBox  Name="comboBox1" Width="120" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ValidBaudRateCollection}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Add these to your `SerialComm` class:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> ValidBaudRateCollection;

public SerialComm()
{
    this.ValidBaudRateCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>(this.ValidBaudRate);
    _serialPort = new SerialPort();
}
```

Finally add these to somewhere in your `Window` (e.g. constructor)

```
SerialComm s = new SerialComm();
comboBox1.DataContext = s;
comboBox1.ItemsSource = s.ValidBaudRateCollection;
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 6;
```

> **NOTE:** THIS WAY YOU CAN BIND YOUR COMBOBOX VALUES, But It may be architecturally incorrect to add an `ObservableCollection` to a class which seems to be in another layer.

Comment: is it possible to omit SelectedIndex="6"? can i get values from binding?

Comment: do you have a suggestion on the proper method of creating the class for this purpose? a keyword should get me started.

Comment: @publicENEMY Yes, It is possible to omit it.
It depends what architecture you are using (MVP, MVVM or ...). Then you may define additional classes and do your job. But the whole idea for binding can be see from my answer.

Comment: You are setting your `ItemsSource` in both XAML and in the code.  There is also no reason to introduce a new `ObservableCollection<int>` unless the items in the list might change.

Comment: @BrentStewart I updated the code several times, so these things happens. In the case of `ObservableCollection` you are right but maybe he wants to make some changes, I wanted to show him more general case.

Answer (score 1):

for the "9600" to be the default baud rate  you need to add the line

```
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 7;
```

as 9600 is at 7th place

Hope it helps...

Comment: is it possible to get the default values from binding?

Comment: You are hardcoding the default value and not programmatically binding it so you should already know the default value. Or have i not  understood your query..

Comment: I did not hardcode the default value. I know the default value because from the textbox binding which shows the default binding. when i try using combobox binding, the default value doesnt shows.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but got me on the right track:

Solved it by adding SelectedValuePath="Content", and saving it to SelectedValue.

```
<ComboBox
          SelectedValue="{Binding LaserBaudRate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="75" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="110" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="300" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1200" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2400" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="4800" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="9600" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="19200" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="38400" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="57600" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="115200" />
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```cs
private int selectedBaudRate;

public Constructor()
{
    SelectedBaudRate = Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedBaudRate;
}

public int SelectedBaudRate
{
            get => selectedBaudRate;
            set
            {
                if (value != selectedBaudRate)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanging();
                    selectedBaudRate = value;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedBaudRate = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox
    Width="80"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableBaudRate}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedBaudRate, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```